# MYsql replication issues. "Error Table xxx.xxx doesnt exist.. Cant even start replication

Tags: mysql, database, replication

Spent two days so far looking though stack overflow answers and google and I just cannot get it working..

Im trying to setup a master / slave replication in mysql/mariadb.. yet when I start the replication. Its just errors on the slave saying tables dont exist.

- Do I need to create the database and tables first?
- If so, what happens if a new table is made on the master? will this break
  replication?

This is the current state of the slave:

```
MariaDB [(none)]> show slave status \G;
*************************** 1. row ***************************
               Slave_IO_State: Waiting for master to send event
                  Master_Host: somedomain.com
                  Master_User: someuser
                  Master_Port: 3306
                Connect_Retry: 60
              Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000002
          Read_Master_Log_Pos: 63687969
               Relay_Log_File: mariadb-relay-bin.000002
                Relay_Log_Pos: 382
        Relay_Master_Log_File: mysql-bin.000001
             Slave_IO_Running: Yes
            Slave_SQL_Running: No
              Replicate_Do_DB:
          Replicate_Ignore_DB:
           Replicate_Do_Table:
       Replicate_Ignore_Table:
      Replicate_Wild_Do_Table:
  Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table:
                   Last_Errno: 1146
                   Last_Error: Error 'Table 'xxxxx.xxxx' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'xxxxxxxxxxxx'. Query: 'UPDATE xxxx SET lastused = NOW(), lingertime = 7 WHERE siteid = 'xxxxxxxxxxx''
                 Skip_Counter: 0
          Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 98
              Relay_Log_Space: 63763807
              Until_Condition: None
               Until_Log_File:
                Until_Log_Pos: 0
           Master_SSL_Allowed: No
           Master_SSL_CA_File:
           Master_SSL_CA_Path:
              Master_SSL_Cert:
            Master_SSL_Cipher:
               Master_SSL_Key:
        Seconds_Behind_Master: NULL
Master_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert: No
                Last_IO_Errno: 0
                Last_IO_Error:
               Last_SQL_Errno: 1146
               Last_SQL_Error: Error 'Table 'xxxxxxxx.xxxxx' doesn't exist' on query. Default database: 'xxxxxxx'. Query: 'UPDATE xxxxx SET lastused = NOW(), lingertime = 7 WHERE siteid = 'xxxxxxxxxx''
  Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids:
             Master_Server_Id: 1
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Do I need to create the database and tables first?

Yes, you have to do that first. You must have the same schemas and tables as you have on master.

> If so, what happens if a new table is made on the master? will this break replication?

Every command you execute on master will be replicated on slave as well. This includes CREATE statements for tables and schemas. So, you won't have any problem.

Comment: Thank you..
If I create the layout first, will it then start filling teh tables with whats on the master or ONLY stuff that happens after replication has started?

Also, if that i sthe case, Wouldnt this cause issues if the slave goes offline at some point?
I suppose what I am asking is, Will the master and slave "sync" and check they are in sync?

Comment: When you execute a command on master, it writes its information to a file called "binlog". Slaves read that and executes all the commands in it from starting point.

Comment: Thanks again.
One last question then..
Is it possible to tell the master to send everything.. Or do i need to grab the whole servers data while its offline, transfer it to the slave and then bring up replication so I dont lose rows / data?
Just wish there was some kind of "send everything and sync" command.

thanks again for your help!

Comment: When you type `show slave status\G` on slave server, it will show you the status of master bin log and at which point your slave is. `Exec_Master_Log_Pos: 651575542 Relay_Log_Space: 651578351`. This will show you if you are behind or not. But I suggest you dump the data from master and restore on slave. Then start replication.

Comment: One important thing: When you dump master, and restore on slave, and then start the replication, you have a lot of duplicate entry errors for the primary keys and unique keys. You have to skip these errors when replication started.